# How to send page cut command to Epson printer

Tags: c#, .net, printing

I'm trying to cut the paper pragmatically by sending paper cut command to the printer (Epson TM U220 with USB port).
I used the printer with Generic/Text Only Driver and Epson printer port which I found after installing
Epson advanced printer driver. 
Printer command code is (GS V m), where m = 0,1,48 or 49 which I found on the device manual.
I would like to know how to send these command to printer by StringWriter.
I use Generic/Text Only printer because it's much faster than using Epson driver.

I'm really new to C# windows and please anyone kindly provide me some lines of code to achieve this. I've been surfing the web for several days and still not found the answer yet. I think I need to send printer command as byte but I don't know how to do :(

Comment: Don't use a driver.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091

Answer (score 23):

Thank you very much Hans. Now I can send Paper cut command by using Microsoft RawPrinterHelper class. I've been seeking this solution for six days. Here is what I've done.

```
string GS = Convert.ToString((char)29);
string ESC = Convert.ToString((char)27);

string COMMAND = "";
COMMAND = ESC + "@";
COMMAND += GS + "V" + (char)1;

PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
pd.PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings();
if (DialogResult.OK == pd.ShowDialog(this))
{
RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName,  COMMAND);
}
```

Comment: I want to make partial cuts on my PAGE on a certain place...is it possible? I am using Star Label Printer.

Comment: RawPrinterHelper class? Where does this come from?

Comment: How do I do partial cut?

Answer (score 6):

For those printing with `netcat` (really easy way to print something without installing any driver), to cut the paper:

```
echo -e "\x1B@\x1DV1" | nc printer.ip 9100
```

Same string like in the c# version, but mapped to hex: `\x1B = ESC` and `\x1D = GS`.

Comment: `printf` works in place of `echo -e`.  On linux, if you have the printer installed in cups, you can also pipe into `lp` as in `echo -e "\x1B@\x1DV1" | lp`.

Answer (score -1):

```
s = Replace(s, "<KESME>", Chr(27) + Chr(105), 1) ' Termal Printer


Chr() +chr()
```

Comment: Please add some context