# How to send cut command in Thermal Printer using PrintDocument in c#

Tags: c#

I am Using `PrintDocument` to print the billing content. But I am unable to send auto cut command. I am using the code below to print content.

```
PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
printDocument.PrintPage += PrintDocumentOnPrintPage;
printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "TestPrinter";
printDocument.Print();
printDocument.Dispose();
```

Can anyone help me which command I have to use for auto cut?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400854/how-to-send-page-cut-command-to-epson-printer

Comment: Is it not possible with printDocument.Print(); command. Do I need to replace it RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried a combination of below two code blocks

```
PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
printDocument.PrintPage += PrintDocumentOnPrintPage;
printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "TestPrinter";
printDocument.Print();
printDocument.Dispose();
```

and at the end, I am sending below commands it's working fine for me

```
        string GS = Convert.ToString((char)29);
        string ESC = Convert.ToString((char)27);
        string documentName ="x"

        string COMMAND = this.textBox.T`ext;
        COMMAND = ESC + "@";
        COMMAND += GS + "V" + (char)1;
        RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(this.textBox1.Text, COMMAND,documentName);
```