# Claim device is not working while using the EPSON TM-T88VI printer once we upgrade it to Advanced driver printer from ADK 270

Tags: c++, thermal-printer, epson, opos

My POS Terminal has installed the Epson driver ADK 2.70E for model EPSON TM-T88VI.
That time the printer was working fine from my POS Terminal application which is in C++.

The registry contains the key in \HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\OPOS.POSPrinter
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFg0L.png)

In Device MAnager,
the device is displaying in the USB prot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKSBZ.png)

In Devices, it is displaying in the Unspecified category,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9qO8.png)
And from my application it is working fine without any problem.

1. Then I Installed the advanced driver version APD 512E on top of it.
2. And then try to print the receipt from my application which uses C++
   code the print is not happening.
3. The OPOS error returning as 106 during the claimDevice funciton.

Device MAnager,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWmcU.png)

Devices,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3EXr.png)

4. If I uninstall the Advanced driver it is working fine from my application, like to know y it not working once we upgrade it to Advanced driver ?

Is there any Language compatibility is there, that c++ is not compatible for this Advanced driver ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be concerned with hardware and software mode settings and related APIs, whether C++ or not.

[Advanced Printer Driver](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=6456&pcat=3&pid=4983) and [OPOS ADK](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=6626&pcat=3&pid=4983) are exclusive and can be used with only one of the settings.

If you want to use OPOS, delete the TM-T88VI related information from the Windows printer list and printer queue, and uninstall Advanced Printer Driver.

If you want to update OPOS, please get it from the above link and update it.

---

**In response to comments:**

As per the question in your comment. However, it depends on the hardware settings. It cannot be handled simply by changing the API used.

If you want to use Advanced Printer Driver, you need to use this utility to change the interface hardware settings from vendor class to printer class.
[TM-T88VI Utility](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=6614&scat=42&pcat=52)

Then print using the standard Windows desktop printer API.
[Printing (Documents and Printing)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/printdocs-printing)

In that case, you will create image data for each page of the print content and print it as bit image data.

If you want to print using printer fonts, cut paper or open a cash drawer, you will need to create and embed RawPrinterHelper.
[Send raw data to a printer by using the Win32 API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows/win32/win32-raw-data-to-printer)
[Print Direct To Windows Printer (EPOS Receipt)](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/704989/Print-Direct-To-Windows-Printer-EPOS-Receipt)
[How to send page cut command to Epson printer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7400854/9014308)

---

**Furthermore:**

You probably can't use it like a question in a comment.

**is that the behaviour of the driver or any other way to add the device to qindows printer without installing Advance printer drivers ?**

To be able to use it as a Windows desktop printer, you need to install some printer driver, even if it is not an Advanced printer driver.

For example, it seems that it is no longer provided in windows 10, but before that there was a generic text only printer driver.
You will need to have some such driver installed.

And perhaps if you install the windows printer driver and create a print queue, it's likely that the connection port will be occupied at system startup and will not be available to others.

This corresponds to the phenomenon of **"3. The OPOS error returning as 106 during the claimDevice funciton."** In the question.

---

**About:** what u mentioning as hardware settings ?

This is the interface mode setting by the TM-T88VI Utility described above.
Printer class or Vendor class of USB.

However, if it is currently available in OPOS, you do not need to consider it.
Rather, it should not be changed.

Comment: You mean to say the application can use either Advanced printer Driver or OPOS ADK, based on what API we are using right ? If so What API does the Advanced drivers uses for example this OPOS ADK uses OPOS_API, so which API will be used for Advanced drivers ?

Comment: Hi, 
I have one doubt, when we install this OPOS driver of EPSON, the device is not displaying in the windows printer catogory, is that the behaviour of the driver or any other way to add the device to qindows printer without installing Advance printer drivers ?

Comment: And another question here is, what u mentioning as hardware settings ?